# Can not drag imageView into viewController

Tags: ios, xcode8

When device turn to landscape, some controls go out of viewController, and I can't drag it to viewController.

[image]

Comment: What kind of question is this? Provide code, a more detailed description of your problem, what you have tried so far, assumptions you can make, etc. … No one can answer a question like that.

Comment: It looks like you did not setup any constraints. If you are new to Storyboard/Autolayout, you should start learning it. See [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) and [Apples Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you can see on your screenshot you have invalid constraints, this can be a problem. If you are using storyboard or xib simple use `sizeclass` to define specific constraints for portirat and landscape mode. Go and checkout Apple guidelines for adaptive UI https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Storyboard with Autolayouts(constraints),Check once your constraints,Or if you are implementing via coding, You can change frame when device is rotating.